# Django Project works on local but not on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

If I try to run the server on local it works without errors but when trying to run it with heroku I get

```
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395710+00:00 app[web.1]: Internal Server Error: /
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395718+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395719+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395720+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395720+00:00 app[web.1]: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "main_chapter" does not exist
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395721+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...er_text", "main_chapter"."chapter_footnotes" FROM "main_chap...
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395722+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395723+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395723+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395723+00:00 app[web.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395724+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395724+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395724+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395725+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = get_response(request)
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395725+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395726+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395726+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/main/views.py", line 10, in home
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395726+00:00 app[web.1]:     last = chapter_list.last()
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395727+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 679, in last
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395727+00:00 app[web.1]:     for obj in (self.reverse() if self.ordered else self.order_by('-pk'))[:1]:
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395727+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 280, in __iter__
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395728+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._fetch_all()
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395728+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395728+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395729+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395729+00:00 app[web.1]:     results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395729+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395730+00:00 app[web.1]:     cursor.execute(sql, params)
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395730+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395730+00:00 app[web.1]:     return super().execute(sql, params)
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395730+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395731+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395732+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395732+00:00 app[web.1]:     return executor(sql, params, many, context)
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395732+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395733+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395733+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395733+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395733+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395734+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395734+00:00 app[web.1]: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "main_chapter" does not exist
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395734+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...er_text", "main_chapter"."chapter_footnotes" FROM "main_chap...
2021-08-24T23:55:05.395734+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
```

I litteraly checked every template, forms, views couldn't find anything about `main_chapter`. I think maybe it is a problem about psycopg2 because when I tried to install it I got so many errors so I installed psycopg2-binary instead. If you require more files, please tell me so.

Comment: The problem is with a query, search for string matching 'main_chapter' in your project. You have also done all migrations correctly? You can try to remake and reapply migrations in your server

Comment: @RedWheelbarrow I'm running the server with gunicorn using the Procfile, could you tell me how do I run additional commands like the makemigrations? (Btw is it better to run with gunicorn or with manage.py directly)

Comment: For remaking migrations follow this steps (note that you will lose any data contained in the tables): run `python manage.py migrate your_app zero`, deletes your migration folders,  then run: `python manage.py makemigrations your_app` and `python manage.py migrate your_app`. For use manage.py you need to activate the virtual enviroment and then run it directly on your server

Comment: ```relation "main_chapter" does not exist```. Did you run ```python manage.py migrate``` on heroku ?

Comment: @Ram I haven't and that was the issue for me

Comment: Then run the migrations and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are all the necessary settings Project/settings.py try use it

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import djoser
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY', 'Optional default value')

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'api.userProfile'


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'api',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'djoser',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'full_db'
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}

# Heroku: Update database configuration from $DATABASE_URL.
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../staticfiles'))

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media")
```

Comment: It seems like your soliton got me a little bit further for that, thanks. I now get Server Error(500) page both in local and in heroku. And I think its about the `debug = True` option, how can I fix it?

Comment: How can your ```settings.py``` suit the OPs settings? Also, the logs clearly says that a table doesn't exist.

Comment: Вам нужно прописать ```ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["yout ip","localhost","127.0 0.1"]```